# What does a comma mean inside of a guard clause?

Tags: swift, syntax

While browsing documentation I came across the following section of code.

```
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else 
    {
        os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
```

I am relatively knew to Swift and I am confused by the meaning of `...UIBarButtonItem, button...`. What is the comma `,` doing here? Is it acting as a logical and `&&`? Is this syntax legal for all control structures (e.g. if statements) in swift, or is it just for guard statements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`,` is almost the same as `&&`.

```
if 1 == 1, 2 == 2 {
    print("dd")
}

if 1 == 1 && 2 == 2 {
    print("dd")
}
```

Both of the above `if` statements will print `dd`.

`,` can be used wherever `&&` can be used, like `while`, `if` and `guard`.

However, with `if let` or `guard let`, as the left hand side does not return a `Bool`, `&&` can't be used and `,` must be used.

```
error: test.playground:4:12: error: optional type 'String?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead
if let a = a && 2 == 2 {
           ^
           ( != nil)
```

Comment: Does `if let` and `guard let` short circuit similar to a logical condition? Or are all statements separated by `,` guaranteed execution at least once?

Comment: It should short circuit.

Comment: So essentially `if let a = optionalA, let b = optionalB {...}` (defined via 2 `let if` separated by a comma `,`) is equivalent to `if let a = optionalA { if let b = optionalB {...} }` (defined via 2 nested `let if`) Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

it's Kind of **if inside if** i.e. nested If

let say `let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem`

now if `sender` is type of `UIBarButtonItem` then it will check condition after `,` i.e. `button === saveButton`

`button` is `saveButton` or not

else it will `return` after 1st condition failed